# Negative side effects of creating a typedef that redeclares a template parameter from an outer scope?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

Sometimes I want to access the type of a template parameter from outside the template. For this, I typedef the parameter as follows:

```
template<typename Vector>
class SomeAlgorithm
{
public:
    typedef Vector Vector;
    // ...
}
```

I feel this is convenient because I can use the same name in client code; it is obvious and simple.

```
template<typename A>
void ComputeSomething(const A& a)
{
    typedef typename A::Vector Vector; 
    Vector v = ... 
}
```

However, ReSharper for C++ issues a warning:

```
typedef redeclares a template parameter from an outer scope.
```

Are there any bad side effects for typedefing the type parameters? Or is there a better way to achieve the same outside of using another name for the typedef?

Comment: Not sure, but, the use of namespaces applied to both inner template & outer template, may avoid that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there any bad side effects for typedefing the type parameters?

Yes, it's invalid. The parameter name is already a typedef-name in the scope of the template, so you can't declare another typedef with the same name.

> Or is there a better way to achieve the same outside of using another name for the typedef?

No. Use another name for the typedef.

Comment: Do you have a source for that it being invalid?

Comment: @Wilbert: C++11 14.1/3 "A *type-parameter* [...] defines its *identifier* to be a *typedef-name* [...] in the scope of the template
declaration.", along with 7.1.3/4 "In a given class scope, a `typedef` specifier can be used to redefine any *class-name* declared in that scope **that is not also a `typedef-name`** to refer to the type to which it already refers."

Comment: @Wilbert: Being ultra-pedantic, it's slightly ambiguous since the name isn't necessarily a *class-name*. But at least [one popular compiler](http://ideone.com/2A3KGQ) forbids it, so you should treat it as invalid if you want portability.